# meteorjs get information from main-yield with iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a small project in meteor and i am using iron-router for the routing.

In my Layout is a main yield and a top-panel yield. Looks like this:

```
<div id="top">
   {{> yield region="top"}}
</div>
<div id="content">
   {{> yield}}
</div>
```

In the main Yield a object is returned which i also need in the top yield field. So my question is if there is a solution to get the object from the main-yield into the top yield in a build-in method ?

Smth like this:

```
// yield region = top Template
{{title}}
```

**title** is in this case a property from the main-yield object. I need to "add" this object to my top-yield template to use all properties in the template and also in the template-helper for the top-yield template.

Comment: how do you set `title` in the main yield?

Comment: It comes from the template Helper which is used for the template in the main-yield. So maybe the question is more "how to get other template helpers" into my template. My example was a bit bad. Sorry for this. The following situation is given. I have a URL with data in it like /url/:_id. Because of this URL the yield template get an object back from a collection. I need to use this object in another yield fields.

Comment: Additional it is possible to read in the top-yield templatehelper the Router.current().params and get the collection again to get all data. But i hope there is a easier way to get this data.

Comment: the easiest would probably be to just use a `Session` variable. Set it in your main yield helper (where the `_id` is known), and then get it in the `top` region

Answer (score 0):

Template helpers are just that – they help the current template. So there's no easy way to access other template's helpers, nor it should be, as this would be against the desired app structure. You should think of a different solution to your problem, I'm sure you'll find plenty.

For example you could use a global helper. It would be accessible from all templates in your application.

You could also move the code from helper to data object in your router path. The data object is accessible to all templates router is rendering – layout template, main yield, named yields. That's the recommended solution if applicable, as it encapsulates your returned object to the smaller required area.